# Help Identifying Children's Book with Easter Bunnies

Tags: identification-request

I know this is a hard, but when I was a kid I had a book about a town that asked some Easter Bunnies to paint the town for Easter or the Easter Bunnies just painted the town or one Easter Bunny painted a bridge or there was one Bunny that painted the town. There were painting and bunnies and the whole town ended up being painted!

To help the painted buildings and things looked almost exactly like how this car came out, same colours and everything.

[image: An image of a painted car in a garage with an adult male and a child]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[The Easter Egg Artists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0689714815)**

It is a story about a rabbit who loves painting and involves him painting the town bridge.

Here is an image from the book of the painted car:
[image: Painted car]

You can also see the illustrations of the book in this YouTube video reading: [The Easter Egg Artists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssWeRR04wog) (9 minutes).